# Google Map Polygon / Rectangle event to draw user editable square

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying very hard today to code something that will allow user to resize square over google map. I have tried rectangle / polygon with no success. When a user will increase the width / height individually this should result changes in both parameter equally.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does your code look like?  Add it to your question so we've got an idea what you're trying

Comment: what have you tried, please post some code (even if only basic)

Answer (score 1):

I got my solution by changing approach and following a bit from this:

[get boundaries longitude and latitude from current zoom google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910847/get-boundaries-longitude-and-latitude-from-current-zoom-google-maps)